# Why XSLT transformation drops all tags and returns a text instead of XML

Tags: xslt

I'm trying some XSLT samples. But in some of them, I only get values inside XML tags.

For example, [try this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) with below XSLT.

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//cd[country='UK']"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="country">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm expecting an XML as the result, like this.

```
<root>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
  ...
  ...
</root>
```

But the result I'm getting is a text, not an XML.

> Hide your heart Bonnie Tyler UK CBS Records 9.90 1988 Still got the
>   blues Gary Moore UK Virgin records 10.20 1990 One night only Bee Gees
>   UK Polydor 10.90 1998 Sylvias Mother Dr.Hook UK CBS 8.10 1973 Maggie
>   May Rod Stewart UK Pickwick 8.50 1990 For the good times Kenny Rogers
>   UK Mucik Master 8.70 1995 Tupelo Honey Van Morrison UK Polydor 8.20
>   1971 The very best of Cat Stevens UK Island 8.90 1990 Stop Sam Brown
>   UK A and M 8.90 1988 Bridge of Spies T`Pau UK Siren 7.90 1987 Private
>   Dancer Tina Turner UK Capitol 8.90 1983 Pavarotti Gala Concert Luciano
>   Pavarotti UK DECCA 9.90 1991 Red The Communards UK London 7.80 1987

Can someone please help me to understand what I'm missing here?

Comment: What is your expected result? -- BTW, your current result is (mostly) the product of the built-in template rules: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule

Comment: I'm expecting complete `cd` elements (XML). Updated the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the *XSLT Tryit Editor* is not fully conformant as any XSLT beyond HTML transformation, their original demo, will render text as possibly part of their web app. So XML tags will not show markup.

Try another online XSLT fiddle engine which shows your current output as below where you return nodes only for `<root>` and `<country>`. Your *country* template targets only one node and the `apply-templates` called before dumps the remaining nodes as text since they have no transformation rules. Also, you redundantly run `//` to search across all children elements of current context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    Hide your heart
    Bonnie Tyler
    <country>UK</country>
    CBS Records
    9.90
    1988

    Still got the blues
    Gary Moore
    <country>UK</country>
    Virgin records
    10.20
    1990

    One night only
    Bee Gees
    <country>UK</country>
    Polydor
    10.90
    1998

    Sylvias Mother
    Dr.Hook
    <country>UK</country>
    CBS
    8.10
    1973

    Maggie May
    Rod Stewart
    <country>UK</country>
    Pickwick
    8.50
    1990

    For the good times
    Kenny Rogers
    <country>UK</country>
    Mucik Master
    8.70
    1995
...
</root>
```

Consider the following adjusted XSLT where you specify `<xsl:copy>` and `<xsl:copy-of select="*">` to return all nodes and text. See demo at this online [xsltransform.net link](http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLK/2), reflecting desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <root>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="cd[country='UK']"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cd">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What you have starts by applying templates to `cd` elements whose `country` is UK.

But you do not have a template matching `cd` - so a [built-in template rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) kicks in and applies templates to **all** children of `cd` in turn. And another built-in template rule copies the text nodes that are children of these elements.

You should change your second template so that it matches `cd` - but the truth is that your entire stylesheet could be shortened to just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:copy-of select="catalog/cd[country='UK']"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```